Where does the frontpage "list new answers and recent edits"?
The current revision of the tag-info for the tag frontpage says:

Unlike the "Questions" text button which only lists new questions, the Front Page lists new answers and recent edits as well.
(Below I have copied the whole text of the tag-info.)

I assume that https://math.stackexchange.com/ is meant by "Front Page" and https://math.stackexchange.com/questions is meant by "Questions".
I see neither new answers nor recent edits on https://math.stackexchange.com/ - am I looking in the wrong place, or is this some outdated information?
I could imagine the phrase "new answers and recent edits" as something intended to talk about recently active questions (i.e., questions bumped by new answers or by edits or by something else) - but those are present on https://math.stackexchange.com/questions (in the Active Tab) and not on https://math.stackexchange.com/.
Naturally, I understand that tag-info is a very official source information - it is possible that the user who edited this tag-info simply made a mistake.
As a side note, I was never sure when people talk about "the frontpage" whether they mean https://math.stackexchange.com/ or https://math.stackexchange.com/questions (or perhaps either of them).
I can see that Meta Stack Exchange has two tags related to this topic - question-lists and homepage; the latter has frontpage as a synonym.

Here is the whole text of the (current revision) of the tag-info

For questions involving the "Front Page" - the list of top questions with activity.
The Front Page is accessed by clicking the site logo and takes you to a list of questions with activity.
Unlike the "Questions" text button which only lists new questions, the Front Page lists new answers and recent edits as well.


EDIT: Based on some feedback I got in the comments, I have edited both the tag-excerpt and the tag-info to something which is closed to the tag-info on Meta Stack Exchange. Please, do not hesitate to edit the tag-info further, if you have some improvements.

Clicking on the Frontpage link in your post does show me the latest edited / asked / answered posts. The time shown below each post  is prefixed by "modified/answered/asked" depending on the activity of the post.

I think the wording approximates active Questions, i.e. ones that have new Answers or recent edits.

I also checked the "Questions" link which is almost same as the front page in content, but it allows me to control the number of questions per page and moving to desired page and further I am notified for any new activity on the top of the page (asking me to refresh). The Frontpage does not have these features of pagination or notification of any activity.

@ParamanandSingh The tooltip on the interesting tab actually says that it is supposed to be tailored for each user - but for me it looks similar to the active tab on the questions page, too. I would say that the formulation in the tag-info seems rather unusual - I am not sure what is meant by "unlike the questions text button" if the two pages seem rather similar.

I checked the history of the tag-info related to Frontpage and found that it was written almost 8 years ago. Maybe at that time the "Questions" and "Frontpage" behaved differently as claimed in tag info, but I am not sure.

At the end of list of questions on  Frontpage we see the message "Looking for more? Browse the complete list of questions," and that leads to Questions page and that suggests that Frontpage is just a short sample of the Questions page (which has a complete list of questions divided into multiple pages).
